# Scrabble wordgame mistake in python

Tags: python, words, nameerror

I'm having trouble with a word game I'm trying to make, scrabble.

A part of my code,where it eventually gives the error, is:

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
"""
Returns True if word is in the word_list and is entirely
composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.
Does not mutate hand or word_list.

word: string
hand: dictionary (string -> int)
word_list: list of lowercase strings
"""
hand_copy = hand.copy()
if word not in wordList:
    return False
for char in word:
    if char not in hand_copy:
        return False
    else:
        hand_copy[char] -= 1
    if hand_copy[char] < 0:
        return False
return True


def play_hand(hand, words):
"""
Allows the user to play the given hand, as follows:

* The hand is displayed.
* The user may input a word.
* An invalid word is rejected, and a message is displayed asking
  the user to choose another word.
* When a valid word is entered, it uses up letters from the hand.
* After every valid word: the score for that word is displayed,
  the remaining letters in the hand are displayed, and the user
  is asked to input another word.
* The sum of the word scores is displayed when the hand finishes.
* The hand finishes when there are no more unused letters.
  The user can also finish playing the hand by inputing a single
  period (the string '.') instead of a word.

hand: dictionary (string -> int)
words: list of lowercase strings
"""
n = HAND_SIZE
display_hand(hand)
print "You may enter '.' if you cannot create a word."
word = raw_input("Please enter a word:")
score = 0
totalscore = 0
while not len(hand) == 0 and not word == ".":
    print word
    if is_valid_word(word, hand, load_words()) == False:
        print "That is not a valid word"
        word = raw_input("Please enter a word:")
    elif is_valid_word(word, hand, load_words()) == True:
        score = get_word_score(word, n)
        print "You word was worth " + str(score) + " points."
        totalscore = totalscore + score
        print "Your total score is: " + str(totalscore) + "."
        print "Here is your updated hand."
        hand = update_hand(hand,word)
        display_hand(hand)
        if len(hand) != 0:
            word = raw_input("Please enter a word:")
print "Your total score is: " + str(totalscore) + "."
return

def play_game(words):
"""
Allow the user to play an arbitrary number of hands.

* Asks the user to input 'n' or 'r' or 'e'.
* If the user inputs 'n', let the user play a new (random) hand.
  When done playing the hand, ask the 'n' or 'e' question again.
* If the user inputs 'r', let the user play the last hand again.
* If the user inputs 'e', exit the game.
* If the user inputs anything else, ask them again.
"""
hand = deal_hand(HAND_SIZE)
while True:
    cmd = raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ')
    if cmd == 'n':
        hand = deal_hand(HAND_SIZE)
        play_hand(hand, words)
        print
    elif cmd == 'r':
        play_hand(hand, words)
        print
    elif cmd == 'e':
        break
    else:
        print "Invalid command."
```

In my opninion this should work. I can start the game, deal a new hand, replay the last hand or end a game. But when I try to make a word from the given letters it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "wordgames.py", line 257, in <module>
  play_game(words)
File "wordgames.py", line 241, in play_game
  play_hand(hand, words)
File "wordgames.py", line 204, in play_hand
 if is_valid_word(word, hand, load_words()) == False:
File "wordgames.py", line 163, in is_valid_word
  if word not in wordList:
NameError: global name 'wordlist' is not defined
```

I've been trying a lot, but nothing helps... Please can somebody help me fixing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your traceback doesn't correspond with... itself! `if word not in wordList:` would **not** cause the error `name 'wordlist' is not defined`. The indentation is also broken in the code you've posted. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should not remove the original question! One of the main points of stackoverflow is so that *other people* also benefit from the answers...

Comment: Oh sorry, I will keep that in mind for in the future :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clearly stated at the bottom of the traceback:

```
File "wordgames.py", line 163, in is_valid_word
  if word not in wordList:
NameError: global name 'wordlist' is not defined
```

ie you don't define `wordList` - the input variable is called `word_list`.

Also you should fix the indentation in your question to make it clear where the function definition ends and you return to global scope.

As jonsharpe points out, your traceback is also inconsistent (`wordlist` instead of `wordList`)

Comment: Thanks! I've edited it, the error is gone. But now with every word I enter, it says it's not a valid word....

Comment: @Mr.X - if this answered your original question you should accept the answer, and start a new question if you have one.